# Atomicity of multiple database transactions on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, atomic

My question's pretty simple, but I'm somewhat new ruby on rails (and web programming at that) and can't find a good answer.  How do I ensure that two (or more) database transaction occur atomically on Heroku?

Can I code the application with mutexes, as I would any multi-threaded application, and expect it to work properly in a distributed server environment like Heroku?  If not, what's the best way to ensure the atomicity of two or more database transactions?

I know Heroku uses PostgreSQL which lets me acquire an array of database locks, but these locks only persist for one transaction.  Furthermore, I'm familiar with mutexes (and pthreads) to synchronize multi-threaded applications, but I'm not sure if these conventions will work as expected on Heroku, especially if my actual application code is running on multiple servers.

EDIT

I definitely should explain what I'm trying to do a little more.  I need to make two calls to the database.  The first call is a read of a boolean value.  If that boolean value is true, I need to do some action, and if it is false I need to do something else.  If I read a TRUE, then I need to do some other stuff (interface with external APIs etc...), and if that succeeds then I need to set the boolean to false.  The problem is that I don't know how to avoid the situation where multiple clients read true from the database, when, in actuality, one client is en route to write false but hasn't yet completed the other stuff I need to do before writing false.

Comment: It would help to know why you need 2 separate transactions.  What prevents you from just putting more actions into a single transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that *might* work:

Modify your boolean field to allow storing a tri-state variable. (Date/time might be nice too, I'll explain in a bit.)

Then code the operations like this:

```
begin transaction
    read flag
    if true
         set flag to "processing" state
    if false
         perform other activity
commit
```

If the flag was `true`, then it will now be set to `processing`; call the external API, do whatever, and when the results are known:

```
begin transaction
    read flag
    if "processing"
        set flag to false
    if true
        warn loudly
    if false
        warn loudly
commit
```

Of course, if the process handling the external API dies or blocks for too long, you'll want to know, and be able to recover. That's why it would be nice to store a date/time into the flag -- if it has been in the state `processing` for six minutes, then kill it and restart.

There would be something nice about using posix semaphores or similar tools, but I would expect your Rails backend processes might execute on different machines from minute to minute.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm definitely going to give this a try.  There still seems to be a "race condition" possible if two processes manage to arrive at the API stage and successively read a "processing" flag state in the second block of code.  However, the likelihood of that happening is very low (I think).